# CodeIgniter creating Controller instance variables shared between functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

I'm trying to put an object in a instance variable and then have acces to it from all the functions in the controller, but it is not working.

Here's the code

```
<?php
    class GestirePost extends CI_Controller {

    private $temp_posts;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('post');
    }

    public function A(){

        $post = new Post();           
        $this->temp_posts = $post;
        echo gettype($this->temp_posts);
        // PRINTS OBJECT
    }


    public function B(){

        $post = $this->temp_posts;
        echo gettype($this->temp_posts);
        //PRINTS NULL

    }
```

}

As you can see, even if i set $temp_posts as Post in A function, when I try to print it in B function it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: For that to work, `A()` would have to be called before using the variable in `B()` ... I don't see where you're calling `B()` or `A()` from the other. If you're loading page `/A/` in the browser, then page `/B/` in the browser and expecting the variable to be available, that's not the way class variables work. It sounds more like you want to put some information in the Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is not persistent  (PHP is scripting language)

In other words once you call function  via browser( i.e.  /GestirePost/A) it goes through series of files, loading classes, etc reaching the controller and printing what needs to be pritned. Eventually it finishes and stops there.

So when you call another function (( i.e.  /GestirePost/B) another instance is created and everything again starts from beginning (you class initializations, etc). So your A function, really never got executed from PHPs point of veiw.

To use data from function call to function call (or rather form another instance to other) we use database or cookies.